# scanf(%s) an issue with EOF

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks

Im using scanf because we must use it.
 the problem is the following :
(thats just an example of the problem):

```
    int main() {
        char ch [10]={0};
        scanf("%s",ch);

        printf("%s",ch);
    }
```

if i run the program and enter for example : word^Z
when ^Z is EOF.
the program stays in place, stuck in the scanf, althogh i did type word then ctrl+z then Enter. but somehow it stays in the scanf, its the same thing with redirection, like its not a problem with ctr+z or anything.

i hope that i can get some help

thanks in advance,
totally apprecaite it :)

Comment: Which operating system? ^D is EOF on Linux, ^Z is EOF on Windows.

Comment: windows, ^Z is always eof and it works,except with scanf %s

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` uses whitespace as a delimiter to store the read data into various fields. From the command line, entering <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd> only puts the `EOF` character into the input stream and `scanf()` continues waiting for whitespace. If you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, `scanf` will receive the whitespace character, and everything including the `EOF` will be stored into the `ch` array.

Here's a sample run. The first line is the input, and the second line is the output.

```
Hello^Z
Hello→
```

Comment: but what the hell is this arrow thing?
Also i tried with getchar, i put while(c!=EOF)c=getchar();
And if c==EOF, it should return 0, i go on and enter chars like abc^Z
and then it just doesnt go to the EOF, so weird?

Comment: Well, obviously the EOF is a non-printable character, but since you have put it into a char array, it has to be printed as part of the string. That's the arrow thing.

Comment: `getchar()` returns int to accommodate `EOF`. If you compare the returned value as a char, it would never match `EOF`. Try comparing it as an int and it should work.

Comment: There is no EOF character!!  When the stream is closed, `getchar` returns EOF.  Typing ctrl-z does not "[put] the EOF character into the input stream`, it just closes the stream.  Whenever you see the phrase `EOF character`, it is wrong.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for pointing that out. The `EOF character` in the answer is a slip, and not intentional. What I had meant was, the invalid character would be substituted with a special EOF indicator. (On Windows, it is the ASCII code 0x26.)

Comment: Thank you guys,to check for EOF i simply had to add if((scanf("%s",ch)==1)

Comment: I am not sure you are doing it right. `scanf` returns the number of fields successfully read. It does not check for `EOF` per se.