# EOF is not working properly in c as well printing is also absurd

Tags: c, file, input, output, eof

In my code i am taking input from console and write it on a file "test",i am taking input from console until i encounter the EOF (**(fscanf(stdin,"%c %s %d %f",&a,b,&c,&d))!=EOF**) as fscanf returns EOF if we enter EOF(ctrl+Z) at time of scanning.  But my code is not stop after taking one EOF,it taking two or three EOF for scanning termination.I manually check that first EOF returns nothing ,Second EOF returning one and third EOF returns -1.After scanning terminations it also print absurd thing.
My code is given below

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    char a,b[100];
    int c;
    float d;
    f=fopen("test","w");
    if(f==NULL)
        printf("error");
    while((fscanf(stdin,"%c %s %d %f",&a,b,&c,&d))!=EOF)
        fprintf(f,"%c%s%d%f",a,b,c,d);
    fclose(f);
    f=fopen("test","r");
    while((fscanf(f,"%c%s%d%f",&a,b,&c,&d))!=EOF)
        printf("%c %s %d %f\n",a,b,c,d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please give your exact test input

Comment: Maybe it has to do with pressing ^Z two times to emulate EOF if you are not on an empty line. Your program behaves as expected when ^Z is pressed as the first input.

Comment: As for why you'd have to press more than two times, is because fscanf returns EOF only when end of file is reached before first matching conversion or failure occurs. So you have given some input and then press ^Z (2 times), then fscanf won't return EOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posted code does not handle newline characters correctly. A second line of input will begin with `\n`, left from the previous line of input, and this character is matched by the `%c` conversion specifier. When `EOF` is signalled from the keyboard, this match has been made, so the `fscanf()` function returns `1` instead of `EOF`. The second time that `EOF` is signalled, no characters remain in the input stream, no matches are made and `EOF` is returned.

This also explains the garbled output in part, since the second line written to the file begins with the `\n` character instead of the intended character. Additionally, the call to `fprintf()` that writes to the file leaves no space between fields, so the later attempt to read back the data fails.

Also, while the code checks to see if the file has successfully opened the first time, nothing is done if it has not. Here is a version of the posted code with corrections, which exits with an error message if the file fails to open, and which also prints an error message if the file fails to close, exiting if the file fails to close before it is reopened.

A space has been added to the beginning of the `fscanf()` format strings so that initial whitespaces, including newline characters, are skipped. Spaces have been placed between the directives of the `fprintf()` format string, with a `\n` at the end, so that the fields can be recognized by subsequent calls to `fscanf()`. Note that without width specifiers for `%s` in the `fscanf()` format strings, there is a risk of buffer overflow. But even with this improvement, if the input strings are too large, input will be garbled with extra characters. It would be better to use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`, with more careful validation of input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    char a, b[100];
    int c;
    float d;

    f = fopen("test", "w");
    if(f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file for writing\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((fscanf(stdin," %c%99s%d%f", &a, b, &c, &d)) != EOF)
        fprintf(f,"%c %s %d %f\n", a, b, c, d);

    if (fclose(f) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to close file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    f = fopen("test", "r");
    if(f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file for reading\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while((fscanf(f," %c%99s%d%f", &a, b, &c, &d)) != EOF)
        printf("%c %s %d %f\n", a, b, c, d);

    if (fclose(f) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to close file\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample interaction. A newline terminates each line of input:

```
λ> ./a.out
a first 3 3.14 
b second 42 2.71828
a first 3 3.140000
b second 42 2.718280
```

Comment: Very very thanks  you for your answer.I am not expecting such answer.But, in this code also the reading is not terminating on encounter of first EOF.Is it possible to terminate reading on first encounter of EOF.

Comment: It does terminate with first `EOF` for me. Can you add an example of your input to your question?

Comment: for the same sample input given in your solution i have to give two EOF for termination of scanning.But, i am using codeblocks for compiling code.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I needed to add a newline to the `fprintf()` that writes the file, so above code is updated. Did you press enter after the last line of input, before pressing **Ctrl-Z**?

Comment: To add, `fscanf()` needs to encounter the `EOF` on a line by itself to function as you intend. [You may want to have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313344/scanfs-an-issue-with-eof).

Answer (score -6):

fscanf() returns number of items successfully read. It does not return EOF. Check this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm

Comment: [man fscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf): "The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is also returned if a read error occurs"